# Sending mail using SendGrid in Groovy - Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, sendgrid

I was using smtp server with Username password to send mail using the below function.

```
def sendEmail() {
   
    AsynchronousMailMessage message = asyncMailService.sendMail {
        // Mail parameters
        to appointmentDetails.emailAddress
        from AppConstant.EMAIL_SENDER
        subject emailSubject
        html emailMessage
    }

}
```

SMTP details are stored in application.groovy.

```
grails {
mail {

    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465
    username = "XXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"
    password = "XXXXXXXXX"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
   
}
```

}

So this was working fine. Now our team wants to use SendGrid for achieve sending mails. I have got the API key, Key Name and other details from SendGrid Team and also have whitelisted my IP in sendGrid configuration. How can i implement that?

Have added below config in application.yml

```
sendgrid:
  api: '${SENDGRID_APIKEY}'
  from: '${SENDGRID_FROM_EMAIL}'
```

Comment: Please add the code/config you have tried and how it failed (e.g.
errors, stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @subham are you able to figure out?

Comment: Yes i used some library